# How to overwrite an Angular module/component/service in a project?

Tags: angular

I've a main Angular application structured in modules. Now I have to develop another application which is 95% equal to the main application. That's why my idea was now to create a project and import/use all required parts (modules, components, services etc.) from the main app.

```
src
|
|---main_app
|   |--- shared
|   |--- services
|   |--- core
|   |--- module1
|   |--- module2
|   |--- ...
|
|---project_app
|   |--- shared
    |--- services
    |--- core
    |--- lazy load module1
    |--- lazy load module2
```

In my `main_app` module all relevant parts are imported.

```
@import { Handler } from 'main_app/services/handler';

@NgModule({
    imports: [...]
    ...
    providers: [Handler]
})
```

and use the service in a component, like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Handler } from 'main_app/services';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    /** */
    constructor(private handerService: Handler) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now comes the (for me) tricky problem in the project. I do the same like above but in the project:

```
@import { Handler } from 'project_app/services/handler';

@NgModule({
    imports: [...]
    ...
    providers: [Handler]
})
```

But now my `LoginComponent` fails because it refers to the wrong `Handler` and doesn't use the handler from `project_app`.
It's obvious that it will fail because I need to tell Angular anyhow that it has to use the correct handler, but now? Can anybody give me a helping hand, please?

Comment: I know it's quite a change, but if you are just starting with refactoring, the better way would be to have 3 projects in this case. One project would be like a library with shared components, services, etc. And you would have 2 projects that are applications that depend on this library. Also services inside this shared library should never be provided there, only in the projects that use it, because library is not an application on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I would not spit this like you. Use a shared library which have all needed Services and so on.

But now to your explicit problem. The `providers` property can have more then one parameter/properties. You can *provide* any and set `useClass` to the Handlers class.

```
providers: [
    ...
    {provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeService}
]
```

Read all about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/providers) in the official docs.

Comment: thank you but if I understand you right, this would mean that I have to include all `HandlerService` classes/implementations in a single shared library, even if they are used only by the project? Doesn't look the best solution for me, in terms of "clean code structure"...

Comment: If it all "one" thing, share it. Have they all other functions to handle, use it per component.